# Error during creation self-signed SSL with openSSL

Tags: api, ssl, openssl, self-signed

I want create restAPI with self-signed SSL.I install openSSl and want generate key with this command

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
```

but I get error.

```
Can't open "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin openssl.cfg" for reading, No such file or directory

202E0000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin openssl.cfg, r)

202E0000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
```

I try

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin openssl.cfg
```

but it dont solve my problem

Comment: Very likely the file you specified simply isn't there. Basically you are specifying a file named `bin openssl.cfg` in the directory `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\ `.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I checked, there is openssl.cfg file in C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin

Comment: If the `openssl.cfg` is in `....\bin` then the setting should be `set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg`, i.e. the last space in your setting should be instead a  \.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you , it solved my problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `openssl.cfg` is in `....\bin` then the setting should be `set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg`, i.e. the last space in your setting should be instead a\